# node.js, express4, ejs routing exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs, express-4

I've been writing my first node.js/express test web-app and faced a problem with routing (I think so, but I'm not sure) while developing. Here are some debug info about my problem. I'm using Express 4 and trying to connect router like this:

```
 var router = express.Router();
 ...
 app.use(router);
```

Error log:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at /Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/app.js:77:11
    at Layer.handle_error (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:310:13)
    at /Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at next (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:121:14)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:97:5)
    at next (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
    at next (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/user1/Documents/work/habitsapp-node-app/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:120:7)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:107:17)
```

app.js file

```
var express = require('express');

var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');
var config = require('config');
var mongoose = require('lib/mongoose');
var session = require('express-session');
var log = require('lib/log')(module);
var HttpError = require('error').HttpError;
var multer = require('multer');
var router = express.Router();

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.engine('ejs', require('ejs-locals'));
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static('public'));

var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);


app.use(session({
  secret: config.get('session:secret'),
  key: config.get('session:key'),
  cookie: config.get('session:cookie'),
  store: new MongoStore({mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection})

}));



app.use(require('middleware/sendHttpError'));
app.use(require('middleware/loadUser'));

app.use(router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

require('routes')(app);



app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (typeof err == 'number') {
    err = new HttpError(err);
  }

  if (err instanceof HttpError) {
      res.sendHttpError(err);
  } else {
    if (app.get('env') == 'development') {
      app.errorHandler()(err, req, res, next);
    } else {
      log.error(err);
      err = new HttpError(500);
      res.sendHttpError(err);
    }
  }
});


var server = app.listen(config.get('port'), function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  log.info('HabitTracker app listening on port ' + config.get('port'));
});
```

loadUser.js

```
var User = require('models/user').User;

module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    req.user = res.locals.user = null;

    if (!req.session.user) return next();

    User.findById(req.session.user, function(err, user) {
        if (err) return next(err);

        req.user = res.locals.user = user;
        next();
    });
};
```

Comment: What's on line 77 of app.js?

Comment: app.errorHandler()(err, req, res, next); , but I defined it like this var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');

Comment: and errorHandler is a npm package?

Comment: And  you added it as a property of `app`?

Comment: Looks like you're just improperly using the errorhandler module. Suggest reading documentation again.

Comment: yes, of course.. but..  I've changed a bit my code to of errorHandling to app.use(errorHandler()); and this removed exception from WebStorm console, but I think that problem still exists because page that I'm trying to access is not accessible.. my browser just wait for resoponse for a long time... this problems appeared after I added **loadUser** midleware..

Comment: @ViacheslauPautaran if you tried what the docs suggested then you should also mention that, as that is the first thing people might suggest when you're using the wrong syntax

Answer (score 1):

This line of code should be

```
  if (app.get('env') == 'development') {
  app.use(errorhandler());
} else {
  log.error(err);
  err = new HttpError(500);
  res.sendHttpError(err);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing here, but `app.errorHandler` is undefined. The `()` that follow `app.errorHander` cause your error message `TypeError: undefined is not a function`.

Also, you require `errorhandler` with this code `var errorhandler = require('errorhandler');`, but you reference it as `errorHandler`. Your casing doesn't match.

This has nothing to do with the express router or ejs.